# Logging into website failure

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, web, webbrowser-control

I did look into tutorials obviously but the html I have is different and I tried a lot of things (the code I will post is the last thing I tried). I will provide you with the html too.

```
   WebBrowser1.Navigate("THE_WEBSITE")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tbtLoginID").SetAttribute("onfocus", "javascript:$(this).val('ID_GOES_HERE');$('#wrong_password_board').css('display','none');")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tbtPassword").SetAttribute("value", "PASS_PROBABLY_GOES_HERE")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("div_123").SetAttribute("onpress", "rockLogin($('#loginform'))")'
```

And this is the HTML (I think it's everything that matters, the website is 
www.microvolts.com anyway)

```
<form id="loginform" action="/Account/login" method="POST">
        <div class="left1"> </div>
        <div class="login_info1">
            <div class="icon_rh">
            </div>
            <div class="floatleft" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">
                <input id="tbtLoginID" width="110px" maxlength="25" height="17px" class="text_box" value="Login ID" tabindex="1" onfocus="javascript:$(this).val('');$('#wrong_password_board').css('display','none'); "> 
            </div>
            <div class="floatleft">
                <div id="loginLoginIdDiv1">
                    <input type="text" onfocus="javascript:$(this).val('');$('#wrong_password_board').css('display','none'); " value="Password" tabindex="2" class="text_box" name="passwordFaked" size="20" width="110px" style="display: none;">
                    <div id="loginPasswordDiv2" style="">
                        <input id="tbtPassword" width="110px" type="password" tabindex="2" maxlength="25" height="17px" class="text_box"> 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="wrong_password_board" class="wrong_password wrong_passwordid ErrorMsg" style="display: none;">
            <div class="topleft"></div>
            <div class="topmiddle">Invalid Login ID and/or Password.</div>
            <div class="topright"></div>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="login_info2">
            <div class="row1">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fbConnect();" class="login_facebook"><span class="left"></span><span class="middle">Login</span><span class="right"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="row1" style="width: 80px">
                <span style="float: left; margin-right: 3px;">
                    <div id="div_123" class="toplogin RockButton" style="width: 60px; height: 19px;">
                        <div id="123" onclick="rockLogin($('#loginform'))" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="rbtdiv">
                            <div class="text">
                                Login</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="rbtmask" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; display: none; background: grey;
                            opacity: 0.2; cursor: default; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </span>
                <div class="btn_question forgetPasswordButton ">

                    <div id="ifClickThisBtn" style=" display:none;" data-ifclick="false"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="forgetPassword" class="tip_forgot_password">
                            <div class="ajaxLoadingMask">
                                <img src="/images/ajaxLoading2.gif" style="margin-left: 150px; margin-top: 9px; position: absolute; display: block;" class="ajaxLoading" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="lefttfp">
                                <div class="l1l"></div>
                                <div class="l1r"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="middletfp">
                                <div class="closetfp"></div>
                                <div class="title">Forgot Password or Login ID</div>
                                <div class="email_form">
                                    <input type="text" value="Enter registered email" name="emailAddress" class="password_recovery_textbox">

                                    <div class="wbtn1 formSubmitBtn" onclick="javascript:forgetPassword();return false;" style="float: left; margin: 2px 0px 0px 5px; cursor: pointer;">
                                   <span class="wbtn1_left"></span><span class="wbtn1_middle" style="padding-left: 10px;
                                    padding-right: 10px;">Submit</span><span class="wbtn1_right"></span></div>
                                    <div class="wrong_email"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="invalideEmailAddress" style="display:none;"> Please enter a valid email address.</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="righttfp"></div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right1"> </div>

        </form>
```

The login form has javascript elements so I figured I could just write it with the right login into it, but nah.
When I run it I get an error from the first line: `System.NullRefferenceException`, all my codes gave that.

I have to admit I probably didn't do all the research I could but I need to do this fast and this is the last thing that may help me.

Comment: You must wait for the web browser to load the page before you start interacting with it. Subscribe to the [**`DocumentCompleted` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) and do your modifications from there.

Comment: I will look at it and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mention above in the comment's by @Visual Vincent you need to add the `DocumentCompleted` event. This event is raised when the document has finished loading.

```
Private docCompleted As Boolean = False 'put this at class level

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        If docCompleted Then Exit Sub
        If WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tbtLoginID") IsNot Nothing Then
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tbtLoginID").SetAttribute("value", "YOURUSERNAME")
        End If
        If WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tbtPassword") IsNot Nothing Then
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tbtPassword").SetAttribute("value", "YOURPASSWORD")
        End If
        If WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("div_123") IsNot Nothing Then
            WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("rockLogin")
        End If

        docCompleted = True
    End Sub
```

The code above check's each element to ensure it not nothing and if it's not then we can set the attributes we would need. Also we can `InvokeScript` of the document for example: `rockLogin`, this script does the login. The `docCompleted` prevents the page from doing postback's as when it's finished and you set the attributes it want's to reload the page etc... it's not required but it prevented multiple postbacks when I tried.

On another note you didn't mention if you were doing this in a click event or what, if so set the `docCompleted` to false before navigating to your page so the variable is reset each time...

**Note: Tried and Tested** - please don't post your login credentials either on a public forum...

Comment: I still get the same errors sadly, at the beginning of the code to, as always. And yea, I was careful to not include them but in the second edit I forgot :(

Comment: What errors, you didn't mention that. The code above pasted in a new solution ***works just fine***, you need to update the issues you are having.

Comment: @Aixiom that is because you are doing it in a click event, it has to be in the event I said above... hence why your error... It seems you didn't do as I mentioned...

Comment: It works now, thanks! Just one more question, I get script error pop-ups, can I somehow hide them?

Comment: @Aixiom put this in load event `WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True`... Also don't forget to up vote if it helped you.

Comment: Welcome! Good Luck!